# Swift 1.2 messed up split()

Tags: swift

```
let separated = split(String(searchText), {find(" ",$0)  != nil}, allowEmptySlices: false);
```

I am getting this error:

> Missing parameter isSeparator in call.

Any ideas?

Comment: I copied the entire line and it works for me. Can you paste the entire error message?

Comment: Missing argument for parameter 'isSeparator' in call

Comment: @TimeString Are you using Swift 1.2?

Comment: @AstroCB: Judging from the question title, (s)he does :)

Comment: @MartinR I was asking TimeString because s/he said that it worked for him/her.

Comment: @AstroCB: Oops, yes, sorry !!!

Comment: @MartinR No worries.

Comment: @AstroCB You're right... I don't think I'm using Swift 1.2.... (I'm still on Xcode 6.2)